# HTML Entity to Unicode Escape Sequence

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this HTML Entity `&#xe900` and I want to use it inside a `<span>` tag. If the HTML is directly present in the file then the icon is getting printed and things are working awesome but if I am using `render` function of the Vue JS:

```
return createElement('span', data, '&#xe900');
```

then it is just printing the text and not the actual icon.

I have read at multiple places that HTML entity won't render directly like this but the Unicode Sequence works in such cases.

Can anyone tell me how to convert the HTML entity to its corresponding Unicode Sequence?

**PS:**

I can not use

```
domProps: {
   innerHTML: '&#xe900'
},
```

in the data parameter of `createElement`, or even simpler `v-html` as I am using `weex` and the resulting code is going to work on mobile devices and there DOM things do not work.

Comment: Do you need a trailing semicolon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the symbol with its Unicode value

```
return createElement('span', data, "\ue900");
```